# Strange formats when exporting to named groups in excel 2010

Tags: excel, sas

So basically we use to export to Excel 2003 files and copy and paste onto a named range into the Excel 2010 report spreadsheet. I have streamlined this by having SAS output values directly into the Excel 2010 report spreadsheet using libref.

Everything is working perfectly and the named ranges are changing nicely and so far the data is good except in some cells I would have them randomly centered and some cells would have a bolded border. There doesn't seem to be any discernable pattern with these strange format occurances. Can anyone explain this?

The SAS code I am using is just the usual Libref and data step. The data itself is good.

Thanks

Comment: LibRef is not bug free.  I couldn't find any examples that match your situation exactly, but for the other formatting bugs the solution is to apply a format before exporting.

Comment: Asssuming libref and then a data step? Same as above, format the area before the export and it should maintain the formats. Check for conditional formatting in the workbook as well.  If that doesn't work post code, I use this successfully a lot without any issues.